Pyspark - Repeat value until change in column
I have a dataframe with this structure



Order Number
Line Number
Item
Type




12345
1
1001
Parent


12345
2
1002
Child


12345
3
1003
Child


12345
4
1004
Child


12345
5
1005
Parent


12345
6
1006
Child



I would like to add a column which shows the "Parent Item" for each item. The parent item is the first parent type that each child follows. There are no relationships or links to use. Line Number dictates the children for each parent.



Line Number
Item
Type
Parent Item




1
1001
Parent
1001


2
1002
Child
1001


3
1003
Child
1001


4
1004
Child
1001


5
1005
Parent
1005


6
1006
Child
1005



The parent item number must repeat until a new parent is found. I have tried adding a LAG column to do checks but couldn't quite nail down the logic. I felt like I needed more than one column but couldn't do it.
I've also tried a window function to "group" them together by row number, partitioning by order number and type but that doesn't work as it separates the parents from the children.

Try this:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = df.withColumn(
    "Parent_Item",
    F.last(F.when(F.col("Type") == "Parent", F.col("Item")), ignorenulls=True).over(
        Window.partitionBy("Order Number").orderBy("Line Number")
    ),
)

df.show()

Output:
+------------+-----------+----+------+-----------+
|Order Number|Line Number|Item|  Type|Parent_Item|
+------------+-----------+----+------+-----------+
|       12345|          1|1001|Parent|       1001|
|       12345|          2|1002| Child|       1001|
|       12345|          3|1003| Child|       1001|
|       12345|          4|1004| Child|       1001|
|       12345|          5|1005|Parent|       1005|
|       12345|          6|1006| Child|       1005|
+------------+-----------+----+------+-----------+


Code only answers are frowned upon, you really should add an explanation.
